# react-native ethers.js createwallet com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: c#, react-native, etherscan

When I import ethers and create a new wallet, it will show this problem and it's once in a while

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

var wallet = ethers.Wallet;
let newWallet = wallet.createRandom();  //this is where the problem is shown, when I annotate this line, it's gone
```